# monitor IO of a running user's executable file read/write

Tags: process, monitoring, executable

How to monitor IO of file read/write by a running user executable's, just like Windows Process monitor when being set to file-related monitoring only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iotop`.  One option is to use the `-p` option to specify the ID of the process in which you're interested.  Alternatively, you can use the `-u` option to specify the username in which you're interested.

```
$ sudo iotop -p 253108
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     593.49 M/s
Actual DISK READ:      19.98 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:     603.95 M/s
    TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 253108 be/4 username   0.00 B/s  593.49 M/s  0.00 %  0.00 % dd if=/dev/zero of=./junk bs=4096 count=100000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `htop` as well - it can show columns like RBYTES/WBYTES and IO_READ_RATE/IO_WRITE_RATE.