# from where htop collects IO read/write data for one current user proccess without root?

Tags: io, proc

I cant find a way to capture `htop` output for a single process about IO_RATE IO_READ_RATE IO_WRITE_RATE.

I need it (the last few seconds IO (or just 1s), not the overall accumulated IO) to determine if a process is not working well to auto-restart it.

I cant use `iotop` as it requires root and that will complicate my work flow, mostly because it is clearly unnecessary.

I went thru everything I could at `/proc/$PID/...` but found nothing I could use about IO in bytes. Not that is it not there, just that I could not find it.

So, a way to grab `htop` output thru a pipe could also suffice as a workaround, but is not what I am asking.

I can already grab `top` output about %CPU, but that is not enough, and I could not find IO data in `top`.

Below, every answer elsewhere is bout iotop (no) or htop (unable to capture output) or other apps that did not help, so I decided to ask this question:
[monitor IO of a running user's executable file read/write](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596779/monitor-io-of-a-running-users-executable-file-read-write)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469159/an-htop-like-tool-to-display-disk-activity-in-linux (if `atop` can do it, I still dont get how...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man proc`, the information you are looking for should stand in `/proc/(pid)/io` :

> /proc/[pid]/io (since kernel 2.6.20) This file contains I/O statistics
> for the process, for example:       /proc/[pid]/io (since kernel 2.6.20)…

Of course, you might well not find this pseudo file since it depends on extra stats made by the kernel depending on one config option :

[CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING.html) (Enable per-task storage I/O accounting)

Therefore, you should rebuild your kernel after having made sure this option is set.
As you'll read on the link above, you might well be constrained to select misc. other config options.
[CONFIG_TASK_XACCT](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TASK_XACCT.html) (Enable extended accounting over taskstats) in particular since it defaults to no and CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING depends on it.

---

BTW, I can't guarantee the pseudo file will be readable by anyone but root and the pid owner. There have been lots of discussion some time ago on that matter, it could well then depend on your kernel version.

---

Note : The need for these options can be deduced from the reading of the /usr/src/linux/kernel/tsacct.c code :

```
#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_XACCT
...
#ifdef CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING
    stats->read_bytes   = p->ioac.read_bytes & KB_MASK;
    stats->write_bytes  = p->ioac.write_bytes & KB_MASK;
    stats->cancelled_write_bytes = p->ioac.cancelled_write_bytes & KB_MASK;
...
```

Comment: The file is there for all pids! as trying to grep all files at /proc/$pid doesnt work well, and i focused on files named with "cpu", I completely ignored the "io" file. thx!